# Scatter 3d in Plotly Express - Colab Notebook is not plotting with equal axes

Tags: python, plot, plotly, jupyter, google-colaboratory

Trying to plot a very simple 3d scatter plot with x,y,z axes all equal in length. It is not working.

Code:
'''

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame

pt_num = 100
x = np.random.uniform(-10,10,size=(pt_num,2))
model = np.array([2,2]).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.dot(x,model)
data = np.hstack((x,y))
dats = {'x':data[:,0].squeeze(),'w':data[:,1].squeeze(),'y':data[:,2].squeeze()}
df = DataFrame(data=dats)

import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='x', y='w', z='y',width=1200, height=1200)
fig.update_layout(scene=dict(xaxis=dict(range=[-10,10]),yaxis=dict(range=[-10,10]),zaxis=dict(range=[-10,10])))
fig['layout'].update(width=1500, height=1500, autosize=False)
fig.show()
```

'''

[image: Resulting plot]

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Asked too soon out of frustration. The answer is to add 'aspectmode="cube"' to the scene dict for fig.update_layout:

```
fig.update_layout(scene=dict(xaxis=dict(range=view_range),yaxis=dict(range=view_range),zaxis=dict(range=view_range),aspectmode="cube"))
```